# how to display different images in datalist which are not in database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I'm working for a e-commerce website.. i have product list which are displayed in data list, in that list some of sold products are also displayed. my requirement is to display a image to the product which are sold-out. please help me..

Comment: You'll need to create some kind of a subquery on your data source to set a field indicating if the product is sold out, then check that field in your DataList.  Post some code if you want specific help.

Answer (score 0):

best way to do this is take a image with text of Sold Out written in right top corner with transparent background of same size as of product image so that when you will keep both this image together you will get the feel of sold out and at the same time you product image will also be visible. And switch the upper sold out image as per the query flag by getting whether product is available or sold out.

Comment: i want to display both products which are sold and which are not.. at a time in a datalist..if that product is sold out automatically the image should display that the product is sold out...

Comment: your datalist will have all the products, you need to apply this sold out images only to those products which are sold out. and nothing happens automatic, your need to have a check in your query ie some flag that this product is sold out and based on that flag u need to apply the sold out image. so in all cases where you will get that flag as 1 means that that product is sold out your sold out image will appear

Answer (score 0):

If your data list has bounded to database you should have a field that show number of that product .after that you can understand which product is available and which one isn't.and you can show picture for which one you want.